# Image not being separated into tiles in the correct arrangement using CroppedBitmaps

Tags: c#, wpf

sorry for the vague title, I want to split an image into tiles in wpf using this code:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files(*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpg";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true) {
    ImageStack.Children.Clear();
    int tileHeight = 64;
    int tileWidth = 64;
    this.Resources["masterImage"] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openFileDialog1.FileName));
    BitmapImage samp = (BitmapImage) this.Resources["masterImage"];
    for (int i = 0; i < samp.PixelWidth / tileWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < samp.PixelHeight / tileHeight; j++) {
            CroppedBitmap c = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource) this.Resources["masterImage"],
                new Int32Rect(i * tileWidth, j * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
            System.Windows.Controls.Image a = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            a.Width = 64;
            a.Height = 64;
            a.Source = c;
            ImageStack.Children.Add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the xaml code:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="21,77,884,286"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <WrapPanel  Name="ImageStack"  Width="640"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is what I'm expecting:
[image]

But this is what I'm actually getting:
[image]

Why is this happening?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: the visible scrollbar  is reducing available width, causing images to wrap too early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should start by scanning through height and then width

```
            for (int j = 0; j < samp.PixelHeight / tileHeight; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < samp.PixelWidth / tileWidth; i++)
                {


                    CroppedBitmap c = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource)this.Resources["masterImage"],
                    new Int32Rect(i * tileWidth, j * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
                    System.Windows.Controls.Image a = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                    a.Width = 64;
                    a.Height = 64;
                    a.Source = c;
                    ImageStack.Children.Add(a);
                }

            }
```

In this way you first run through rows and then through columns. That's how WrapPannel works. First you fill the first row with columns then the second and so on ...

Comment: Although MVVM style is prefered way to go with WPF it is irrelevent for this question. By the way MVC can be a better approach if you need to access immages directly in code behind afterwards.